# HTTP Server: Connection closed by foreign host

Tags: c, http, unix, webserver, telnet

Attempting to get this HTTP webserver I found online running after downloading their source files (source: [Webserver](http://www.paulgriffiths.net/program/c/webserv.php)). [Files located at bottom of webpage.]

I attempted to compile it using their Makefile but there were some errors, where I just needed to #include some extra libraries. However, once I got that compiled and running (tested using telnet)

```
telnet localhost <port number>
```

I get the following:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Then after 5 seconds or so it displays the following:

```
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I'm not sure if the person who wrote it is still managing it so I figured I'd ask here. Any ideas as to why connection closes?

I'm running this on a Windows machine connected to a Unix server, so as the program site states, it should be running correctly on Unix machines.

Comment: Please see [ask] -- specifically, the bit about include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

in the file: reqhead.c

in the function: Get_Request()

There is a timed call to `select()`

You can change the timeout value (currently 5 seconds)
 or replace the timeout parameter with a NULL parameter (although replacing with NULL would mean the code, once a connection is established would wait forever.)

Answer (score 0):

First we will see ubuntu system log with this command

```
sudo gedit /var/log/syslog
```

and if you will see this error "execv( /usr/sbin/tcpd ) failed: No such file or directory"
then run this command

```
sudo apt-get install tcpd
```

It will solve your problem (if not then you need to search your system error on google)